# Modify data after Django form submission

Tags: python, mysql, django, forms, django-queryset

I'm looking for let to users the possibility to modify forms which were created in order to correct mistakes during the filling process.

There is some user steps (I'm blocked at the step 4) :

- 1) An empty form is presented on the HTML page
- 2) Users filled the form and click on the submit button which let to 
  validate data and save objects in the MySQL Database.
- 3) I display kind of resume in order to verify if all data are corrects
- 4) I would like to put a button `Modify` just below my resume. Users could modify one or several fields and update the MySQL Database.

The problem is as following : I have not idea about the way to do that (step 4). As I'm beginning with Django, is it possible to get some advices or part of script ?

**views.py** :

```
def IdentityFormulary(request) :

    form = IdentityForm(request.POST or None)

    if form.is_valid() :   
        instance = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('formulaire_traite')

    context = {
        "form" : form,
        }

    return render(request, 'form_Identity.html', context)



def CompletedFormulary(request) :

   identity = Identity.objects.all().order_by("-id")[0]

   context = {
        "identity" : identity,
    }

    return render(request, 'recapitulatif_identity.html',context)
```

**My HTML Template :**

```
<h2 align="center"> Votre formulaire a été validé </align> </h2>


{% block content %} 
Votre personne porte le numéro : {{ identity.id }} 

<h3> Récapitulatif des données enregistrées : </h3>

<li> Civilité : {{identity.title}}</li>
<li> Nom : {{identity.lastname}}</li>
<li> Prénom : {{identity.firstname}}</li>
<li> Sexe : {{identity.sex}}</li>
<li> Date de Naissance : {{identity.birthday}}</li>
<li> Ville de Naissance : {{identity.birthcity}}</li>
<li> Pays de Naissance : {{identity.birthcountry}}</li>
<li> Nationalité : {{identity.nationality}}</li>
<li> Profession : {{identity.job}}</li>
<li> Adresse : {{identity.adress}}</li>
<li> Ville : {{identity.city}}</li>
<li> Code Postal : {{identity.zip}}</li>
<li> Pays : {{identity.country}}</li>
<li> Email : {{identity.mail}}</li>
<li> Téléphone : {{identity.phone}}</li>

{% endblock %} 

<br></br>

<form method='POST' action='/Identity/accueil'> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Retour fiche identité" />
</form>

<form method='POST' action='/BirthCertificate/accueil'> {% csrf_token %}
<input type ="submit" value="Création d'un acte de naissance" />
</form>
```

I saw some functions which could correspond to my step 4 : `Form.cleaned_data` for example but I don't know How I can realize this step.

Thank you !

**EDIT :**

I'm reading part about something like :

```
instance = form.save(commit=False)
instance.save()
```

I think that it's possible to enter data, but not save it immediately in the Database.
I'm on the right way ?

Comment: I suggest you read this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/forms/ and follow the same pattern in your code

Comment: @e4c5 I already read this part, but maybe faster ... I will see in details on I could make this process. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your step one is fine. In step two, you would be over-complicating things if you tried to allow the user to submit a partially valid form, save half of the values, and then let them update the rest. Don't save any values until the form is fully valid.

If you follow that advice, step three will occur when you pass the invalid form back to the template. You'll get a form with correct fields pre-filled and incorrect fields highlighted with the validation error messages helping the user know what they did wrong. See comments in this code for explanation:

```
def IdentityFormulary(request) :

    form = IdentityForm(request.POST or None)  # request.POST includes invalid data

    if form.is_valid() :   # Returns False because user incorrectly submitted form
        instance = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('formulaire_traite')

    context = {
        "form" : form,  # This is the partially-filled, invalid form with error messages
        }

    return render(request, 'form_Identity.html', context)  # This re-renders the template with a partially filled form, _with_ error messages to help the user.
```

Then, your step four needs to change such that the "Modify" button is actually the same "Submit" button. The user is simply re-submitting the same form that was not valid before. Hopefully this time they edit their responses, or they'll get error messages and have to resubmit until the form returns valid. If the form is valid on submission, the database will update on your line `form.save()`.

Comment: Ok, but if the user is re-submitting the same form, values are already filled or he needs to write one more time all of this data ?

Comment: Values would be filled with whatever he entered initially.